# Leaflet GeoJSON Map Buffering

Tags: leaflet, geojson, performance, pan

I am using Leaflet with Custom GeoJSON Layers to display my map. I noticed that the map off-screen is only loaded after releasing the mouse button during a drag.

Hopefully, this demo makes it more clear what I mean:[image: demonstration of issue]

Is there a way to make the map draw before or during a pan movement?

I found the [Leaflet.EdgeBuffer](https://github.com/TolonUK/Leaflet.EdgeBuffer) plugin which would do what I want but it appears to only work for tile layers.

As you can probably tell, the map I am using is fairly simple so memory or performance shouldn't be impacted much by even buffering the whole map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the **map draw** before or during a pan movement?

You're wrong in this assumption: Leaflet has no concept of "*drawing the map*". Rather, the artefact is due to the map's [`L.Renderer`s](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#renderer) not being [updated](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#renderer-update) during a drag interaction.

This is done for performance reasons: updating the vector data in a `L.Renderer` can be very intensive in certain scenarios, particularly in old web browsers, and would cause (very) noticeable jitter.

These artefacts are usually alleviated by making the `L.Renderer`s larger than the map itself: this is done by specifying an explicit `L.Renderer` and [tweaking its `padding` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#renderer-padding). Note that, by default, a `L.Renderer` has an overhand of 10% of the map's size - if you pan the map less than that amount, you'll notice no artefact at all.

Please note that increasing the `padding` of the `L.Renderer`s is a *naïve* approach to alleviating these artefacts: it increases the amount of vector data to actually draw, which means there's a performance hit.

> the map I am using is fairly simple so memory or performance shouldn't be impacted much by even buffering the whole map.

Do not be deceived here: you may think "Simplicity" of the vector data is the deciding factor... but the sizes of the rasterized images (in terms of pixels to be drawn/kept in memory) have an impact on web browsers. Large values of `padding` for `L.Renderer`s mean that you can end up with raster images ten times larger than the user's screen, and again some browsers might have troubles with that.

> Is there a way to make the map draw **before** or during a **pan movement**?

Leaflet already does this: Any `L.Renderer`s in a `L.Map` will automatically update on the [`moveend` event](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-moveend). This will happen when you *release* your mouse button and thus end the drag interaction.

> [...] but it appears to only work for tile layers.

...then you might have noticed that `L.TileLayer`s (and `L.GridLayer`s) behave different than `L.Renderer`s, particularly when it comes to updates during drag interactions and pan animations.

You can use a `L.GridLayer` or `L.TileLayer` to display your data. The two main approaches here are to rasterize your data in advance (AKA ["build your own tiles"](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/)), or turn to [vector tiles](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid). I feel that full explanations of these are out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info clearing up how things work. For my use case, it appears that simply increasing the Renderers padding does the trick fine, without any noticeable performance impact